# jquery autocomplete undefined function

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to use jquery autocomplete but get a undefined function error -

html code & js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#searchtext").autocomplete({

        //source: availableTags, This works.....(static list are working)
        source: function (request, response) {   // This is not working 
            $.ajax ({
                url: '/autosuggest/',
                data: { 'keyword':$('#searchtext').val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    return data
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }

            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
    //open: function() { $(this).autocomplete("widget").css({"width": $(this).width()+6})},
    //appendTo:$( ".cls_comp").parent(),
        select: function( event, ui ) { }
    });
})
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def autosuggest(request):
    json_response = ['value1','value2','value3','value4']
    return HttpResponse(json_response,content_type='application/json')
```

Error :

```
 $("#searchtext").autocomplete({

Uncaught type:undefined is not a function
```

jquery lib used:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including jQuery twice. The second of which is over-riding the first, which has jQuery UI methods included in it. Change your `script` tags to this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, I have to remove - src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"??, Correct?..I did that but same problem

Comment: I had another duplicate entry..It worked once I removed it...Thanks